# Swift String Manipulation

Tags: ios, string, swift

I have converted a double to a string as I think it would be easier to manipulate. I have a string of: `14.52637472` for example.

How can I split it up into 2 variables, one for before the period, and one for ONLY 2 DECIMALS after?

so it should be: `one = 14` and `two = 52`

This is my code to convert into a string: `var str: String = all.bridgeToObjectiveC().stringValue`

I don't know objective C, so I wouldn't really be able to do it that way, and I have read over the swift book on strings, but it does not discuss how to do this, or atleast I could not find that part?

Please would you help me out, want to build the app for my father to surprise him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the double, use NSString's format: initializer  coupled with a format specifier to trim all but the tenths and hundredths column, and convert to string. Then use NSString's `componentsSeparatedByString()` to create a list of items separated by the period.

```
let theNumber = 14.52637472
let theString = NSString(format: "%.2f", theNumber)
let theList = theString.componentsSeparatedByString(".")

let left = theList[0] as String  // Outputs 14
let right = theList[1] as String // Outputs 53
```

As second option using NSNumberFormatter.

```
let decimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(double: 14.52637472)

let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 2
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

let stringValue = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(decimalNumber)
let theList = stringValue.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
```

Comment: Worked! thanks so much! will accept answer as soon as the time is lifted

Comment: @user3723418 Glad to hear it. I've updated my post to include a second way of doing this if you're still interested.

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a bit of a code smell here: much of the manipulation that this very good answer suggests is using the number value as a number. That suggests you *may* not need to convert to string in the first place. Whether that's really the case depends on your requirements, of course.